# Inferring type '1' instead of number

Tags: typescript

I have this code of typescript

```js
type X = (<T extends number | string>(a: T) => (b: T) => T)

const f: X = (a: any) => (b: any) => a + b

f(1)(2)
```

It showing error

```
Argument of type '2' is not assignable to parameter of type '1'.
```

The inferred type in the first argument is `'1'` but I want it to be `number` with same constraints on generics `string | number`.

The types of arguments passed can only be either `number` or `string` i.e. constrained to `string | number`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UAUAeAKlCAPYEB2AJgM5R4CuAtgEYQBOUAPlEcLQJZ4DmAfEgIYAuKGgCUCbsipDR44SIBQ8gMYB7PCygAzIXET8hfPCDHwJSKVEPHZfKAGooVRZqQBGEUgBMIoA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for your case?

```js
type XGen<T extends string | number> = (a: T) => (b: T) => T;
type X = XGen<string> & XGen<number>;
const f: X = (a: any) => (b: any) => a + b;

f(1)(2);
f(1)('2'); // error
f('1')('2');
f([])([]); // error
```

The goal is to direct TypeScript to choose only between `string` and `number` (not guessing any other types that extend their union (such as `1` as in your example)). We achieved this by creating a basic generic helper type `XGen` and creating an intersection type of `XGen<string>` and `XGen<number>` (therefore forcing typescript to choose only between these two).

Comment: No, I want `f` to be a generic function. In my case `f("ab")("cd")` should also work.

Comment: @ShivamSingla In that case defining another function such as `fStr: X<string>` seems much clearer to me. However, I understand that it might not fit into your bigger picture here.

Comment: Declaring other function will violate DRY principal. In code like [this](https://github.com/Jozty/Fae/blob/master/nth.ts) it gets very important.

Comment: @ShivamSingla I updated my solution. Sadly it will allow `f(1)('2')`. I am not sure if you can live with that.

Comment: @ShivamSingla Let's hope the last edit is what you are looking for! :)

Comment: Seems working with this code. Could you please explain little about what is happening in your code so that I can modify it accordingly in my actual code?

Answer (score 0):

why `<T extends number | string>` and not just `<T=number|string>`?

I've just tried

```
type X = (<T = number | string>(a: T) => (b: T) => T)

const f: X = (a: any) => (b: any) => a + b

console.log( f(1)(2) );
console.log( f("1")("2") );
```

Result:

```
[LOG]: 3 
[LOG]: "12"
```

in the same playground as you gave us and it worked just fine.

It's been a while since I last wrote any TS code, but I think when you use `extends` constraint, you're implying that the T will be some derived type and the only type available matching f(1) was some kind of "literal type". I mean, `1` was "upgraded" from `number` to literal type "1" (same mechanisms as with literal-strings-as-types etc, just with numeric-literals instead of string-literals)..

I bet you didn't really mean a X type to be a descendant of Number or descendant of String.. it's feels to me somewhat.. rare..

Comment: In that way, `T` will not be constrained to `number | string`. It will get default type as `number | string`. `f([])([])` will also work, which is not required.

Comment: @ShivamSingla Could you please update your question with these details?

Comment: @gurisko Updated!

Comment: @ShivamSingla `f([])([])` interesting. I didn't expect it to be possible. I'll have to rethink it a few times, because, as I said, it's been a while since I worked in TS :) Gurisko's answer _sound_ to me very similar to what I tried to achieve, but I actually forgot about possibility to denote `&`-intersection types. Very handy feature. I had an impression that `T = number | string` would do exactly that, but apparently not! Thanks.